# How to fix this error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'odict_items'?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm trying to implement the [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403120/getting-django-to-serialize-objects-without-the-fields-field) in django 2.0

```
def get_dump_object(self, obj):
    metadata = {
        "pk": smart_text(obj._get_pk_val(), strings_only=True),
        "model": smart_text(obj._meta),
    }
    return dict(metadata.items() + self._current.items())
```

but I get this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'odict_items'
```

How can I merge a normal dict and an ordered dict?

Comment: flesh out you question some more, what is the code you are running?

Comment: I think, it'll be better if you add the code in **this** question.

Comment: What does your dictionary contain? Integers, floats, strings, a mixture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use `+` with dictionaries when trying to add to one another (unlike lists which support `+` operator).

Use [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) instead:

```
In [47]: from collections import OrderedDict
    ...: o = OrderedDict([(1,2), (3, 4)])
    ...: d = {5:6, 7:8}
    ...: 

In [48]: o+d
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'collections.OrderedDict' and 'dict'

In [49]: o.update(d)

In [50]: print(o)
OrderedDict([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)])
```

Alternatively:

```
In [52]: from collections import OrderedDict
    ...: o = OrderedDict([(1,2), (3, 4)])
    ...: d = {5:6, 7:8}
    ...: 

In [53]: d.update(o); print(d)
{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OR operator`: `|` to [merge the 2 dictionaries in python 3](http://treyhunner.com/2016/02/how-to-merge-dictionaries-in-python/)

```
metadata = {
    "pk": smart_text(obj._get_pk_val(), strings_only=True),
    "model": smart_text(obj._meta),
    "title": smart_text(obj.training_type.name)
}
return dict(metadata.items() | self._current.items())
```