# Storing and retrieving a list of integers in sqlite using django

Tags: python, django

I'm prototyping a JSON API in Django (final implementation will be something embedded such as Civet) in order to have something to test a higher level application against. I need to persist data of the form:

```
{
    someListOfIds: [1, 2, 7, 9]
}
```

The integers mean something to the hardware - they don't correspond to anything else in the db.

I'm using Django 2.1.5 and Python 3.5.2. In my model, `someListOfIds` is currently defined as a CharField so the value is stored as the string `"[1, 2, 7, 9]"`. When I retrieve rows from the db in a view, I pass that field through the `.decode` method of a `json.decoder.JSONDecoder()`, which seems to turn it back into a list of ints. However, attempts to deliver it in that form in a `JsonResponse` result in it being returned in the string-ified form:

```
{
    someListOfIds: "[1, 2, 7, 9]"
}
```

NOTE: Following advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404413/325366), I currently have the following view code to return just the content of the `fields` property, discarding the extra `pk` and `model` properties that would otherwise be included:

```
cfgs = [Configuration.deStringify(x) for x in Configuration.objects.all()]
objs = serializers.serialize('python', cfgs)
cfgs = [d['fields'] for d in objs]
response = { "configurations": cfgs }
return JsonResponse(response)
```

As far as I can tell, it's the serialization to a python object that reintroduces the string-y-ness.

`deStringify` is:

```
def deStringify(self):
    decoder=json.decoder.JSONDecoder()
    self.someListOfIds = decoder.decode(self.someListOfIds)
    return self
```

This is very much a throwaway piece of code - it just needs to serve up correctly structured data for a while. A working solution, without making a fresh start and adding a dedicated REST framework is all I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code. What is `deStringify`? What's the point of passing it through the serializer? Why don't you just pass the list of IDs to the JsonResponse?

Comment: It's to turn the string property (`"[1, 2, 7, 9]"`) into a list property (`[1, 2, 7, 9]`). There's a lot more to this model, so hand-assembling the JSON string isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not describing the *exact* scenario, [this hint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database) from the docs made me suspect that my conversion from string-containing-list-of-ints to actual-list-of-ints was being undone when `serializers.serialize(...)` subsequently read the property. I now perform the transformation after extracting the `fields` property from the python-serialized structure and my JsonResponse now correctly contains the intended list-of-ints.

It's seems like a lot of work and probably reflects me not "getting" the Django way of doing things, and it's certainly not pretty, but it does the job:

```
decoder=json.decoder.JSONDecoder()
all = Configuration.objects.all()
objs = serializers.serialize('python', all)
# Extract the interesting part of the structure
cfgs = [d['fields'] for d in objs]
for key in ['someListOfIds', 'someOtherListOfInts', 'finalListOfInts']:
    [cfg.update({key: decoder.decode(cfg[key])}) for cfg in cfgs]
response = { "configurations": cfgs }
return JsonResponse(response)
```